# ionic2 modal form throws error unexpected value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 app and trying to open a modal from (it's going to be a form) a component.

The modal itself:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class AddCigarFormBuilder {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  private myData: any;
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = builder.group({
      'subject': '',
      'message': ''
    })
  }

  onSubmit(formData) {
    console.log('Form data is ', formData);
    this.myData = formData;
  }
}
```

and it's HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Subject</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="subject" name="subject"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Message</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea type="text" formControlName="message" name="message"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <button block>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>Add</button>
</form>
```

The component from where I am trying to open it:

```
import { AddCigarFormBuilder } from '../form_add_cigar_to_list/add_cigar_form.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'cigar_list',
    templateUrl: 'cigar_list.html'
})
export class CigarList {

    constructor(public nav : NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

        this.nav = nav;
    }

    presentAddCigarModal() {
        let addCigarModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddCigarFormBuilder, 
        {

        }
    );

        addCigarModal.present();
    }
}
```

And it's HTML:

```
<ion-fab right top>
    <button ion-fab color="secondary" (click)="presentAddCigarModal()">
      <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-fab>
```

In my app.module.ts:

```
import { CigarList } from '../pages/cigar_list/cigar_list.component';
import { AddCigarFormBuilder } from '../pages/form_add_cigar_to_list/add_cigar_form.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      deps: [Http]
    }),
    IonicImageViewerModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    CigarList,
    AddCigarFormBuilder,
  ],

  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    CigarList,
    AddCigarFormBuilder,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler, }]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

I didn't change anything in app.component.ts.

This gives me following error:

```
Unexpected value 'AddCigarFormBuilder' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

What am I doing wrong here? If I remove AddCigarFormBuilder from module, then application starts but on clicking the button it throws:

```
ModalCmp ionViewPreLoad error: No component factory found for AddCigarFormBuilder
```

error.

Comment: did you miss @component decorator ?

Comment: Yes correct! Thanks for pointing out, I will just if it works afterwards

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help .